# AngularJS/Bootstrap - DataTables - Turn off certain dropdown filters in footer

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to turn off certain dropdown filters in the footer? This is the API I'm using: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

I don't want all columns to be filterable. Also, is it possible to have the header labels be the default in the dropdown instead of a blank?

Here is my live example: http://live.datatables.net/cufawibi/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual approach is to use a css class to filter which columns can be filterable.

You could also add the column name as selected and disabled in order to display it as the default (included an all values options to disable the filter).

```
    initComplete: function () {
        var api = this.api();

        api.columns('.filtersearch').indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
            var column = api.column( i );
            var select = $('<select></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            select.append('<option selected disabled>"'+$(column.header()).text()+'"</option>');
            select.append('<option value="">All values</option>');              

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
            } );
        } );
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to have the class added from the controller, changed also the table head definition to

```
<th ng-repeat="(i, th) in head" value="{{th.id}}" class="{{th.class}}"><span>{{th.name}}</span></th>
```

[Live example](http://live.datatables.net/gifakocu/1/) (filter only for the "Payload" column, add `filtersearch` class to other columns to enable filtering)

Comment: I changed my code and added `filtersearch` to the columns I would like to filter but it reverted my footer to just labels, no filter dropdowns. http://live.datatables.net/cufawibi/4/ Do you know what I'm missing? Was the code changed anywhere else?

Comment: Cool, it works great - thanks! Couple questions though - is there a way for the dropdown to not have the quotation marks? and instead of having "All Values" as the selection to show all values, can it be the header text without quotation marks?

Comment: Yes sure, check here: http://live.datatables.net/gifakocu/3/ Just removed the quotation marks and set the default to the column name, which also removes the filters.

Comment: Sorry, couple more questions: how can I code my "Clear" button to clear the dropdown filters to show all values again if it is currently filtered? Also, my datepicker input gets cleared but I think the values are still there. So just one question really - how can my "Clear" button clear all filters and have all rows appear in the table again (although this functionality currently works)?

Comment: Here is the code for the clear button (only modified $('#clear').click function): http://live.datatables.net/fukugapu/1/

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working for me. The button used to work on my datepicker (removed filter and showed all rows), but it doesn't work either now. Could you check please?

Comment: The clear button seems to be working fine, removed filters and shows all rows, what are you experiencing? another link just in case: http://live.datatables.net/duxukifu/1

Comment: Oh, I think I used `.dataTable()` instead of `.DataTable()` . It works now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing I discovered through testing. If I'm using 2 filters (datepicker and one of the columns), I have to click "Clear" twice in order for all the rows to appear again. Is there a way around this? I think it is because the values for datepicker are still selected even though the input is empty.

Comment: The datepicker filter through the fields start and end is not working on the live example or i am missing something?

Comment: I'm actually not sure why it doesn't work on the live example, it works fine on my computer.

Comment: Checked it, you were linking to a external js to perform the filters, but that code need a column number according to which column do you want to filter. So i removed the reference <script src="http://carlose.pessoal.ws/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.DateRange.js"></script> and included the code first at the javascript, check that the column selected to filter is "Date Created" (   var arr_date = aData[1].split("/"); 
) Here is working all fine: http://live.datatables.net/nelunesu/1/

Comment: Oh, yeah I forgot I changed the code locally in order to filter. Thanks for catching that! When I included the DateRange code in my main javascript file, the app wouldn't load so I kept them separate. My "Clear" button still has to be clicked twice in order to clear the date filter as well - was there new code for this?

Comment: I updated my code, added a couple functionalities (http://live.datatables.net/cufawibi/7/) - the "Clear" button still doesn't clear everything on the first click and I don't think it's filtering properly. If you select 01/01/2015-01/31/2015, some February 2015 dates still appear.

Comment: I really suggest you to compare your code (http://live.datatables.net/cufawibi/7/) with the last code provided (http://live.datatables.net/nelunesu/1/) and check the working functionality. If you have new issues, post another question describing your new problem so more people could help you.

Comment: I found the difference! I will post a new question for other problems. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a clean way to do this via the API. So this solution will be hacky.

So you'd wrap your logic around an IF block to filter out the columns dropdown filters you don't want to display.

```
api.columns().indexes().flatten().each(function (index) {
    var column, select;

    // You don't want to display the first and the fourth dropdown filter
    if (index !== 0 || index !== 3) {

        column = api.column(i);
        select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
            .on('change', function () {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());

            column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
        });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });

    }
});
```